# cant open exe files on windows server 2012

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-server-2012

I want to install .net 3.5 framework to windows server 2012. I downloaded the installer and when I open the .exe file this window warns me:

[image: here]

How can I install .net framework to this machine?

Answer (score 1):

It pretty much says it in the message. On Server editions, features are not installed using the client windows features "app", but using server manager. You use "add roles and features" in server manager and select .net framework 3.5 under features or you could install using the following powershell-command:

```
Install-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core
```